# WP_query sort by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

```
'post_type'=> 'training',
'meta_key' => 'WTF_date',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => ASC
```

This is what I'm using, I want it to sort by a date in a custom field. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'training',
    'meta_key' => 'WTF_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
        ?><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><?php
        <!-- more... -->
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Check more [on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).